# How to count an array with condition

Tags: php

I have a list of hosts with interface.
The code must count the repeated interfaces per host.
Also at the end the code must show the repeating interfaces X times, per host.

I am asking this because I want to send an alert that X host has a failing X interface or more failing interfaces.

```
$data = array(
    array("192.168.0.1","eth1"),
    array("192.168.0.2","eth2"),
    array("192.168.0.3","eth3"),
    array("192.168.0.1","eth1"),
    array("192.168.0.4","eth1"),
    array("192.168.0.2","eth5")
);
```

I followed other examples in here, but most of them are for simple arrays or if multidimensional example then the examples aren't similar.

I have tried this...

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array("192.168.0.1","eth1"),
    array("192.168.0.2","eth2"),
    array("192.168.0.3","eth3"),
    array("192.168.0.1","eth1"),
    array("192.168.0.4","eth1"),
    array("192.168.0.2","eth5")
);


$counter_data = count($data);

$duplicated_host = array_filter(array_count_values(array_column($data, 0)), function($v) { return $v > 1; });
print_r($duplicated_host);
print ("<br>");

$duplicated_host_keys = (array_keys($duplicated_host));

for ($row_num = 0; $row_num < $counter_data; $row_num++)
{
    $host = $data[$row_num][0];
    $interface = $data[$row_num][1];
    if (in_array($host,$duplicated_host_keys))
    {
        print($host . " " . $interface . "<br>");
    }
    
}
```

The code above is wrong, somewhat working but it is not what I expect...
Is there a simple way to do this?

At the end the output should look like:

```
Host 192.168.0.1 has eth1 repeated 2 times. --> For current data only
Host 192.168.0.1 has eth9 repeated 5 times.
Host 192.168.0.4 has eth1 repeated 9 times.
```

Comment: And "is wrong" means what _exactly_ ?

Comment: It is not sorting the repeated interfaces per host.

Comment: Please describe what output you want to get _exactly_ ...

Comment: Have you got the output you want but not in the correct order? You are printing out values directly from the initial array in the same order that it is already in. You could pass the inital array through a sort function before doing the `for` loop for output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to group double, first host, then by interface.

Then you can looop over this grouping array to show/send the output:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array("192.168.0.1","eth1"),
    array("192.168.0.2","eth2"),
    array("192.168.0.3","eth3"),
    array("192.168.0.1","eth1"),
    array("192.168.0.4","eth1"),
    array("192.168.0.2","eth5")
);


$result = [];

foreach ($data as $arr) {
    [ $host, $nic ] = $arr;
    if (!isset($result[$host])) {
        $result[$host] = [];
    }
    if (!isset($result[$host][$nic])) {
        $result[$host][$nic] = 0;
    }

    $result[$host][$nic]++;
}


foreach ($result as $host => $nics) {
    foreach ($nics as $nic => $count) {
        echo "${host} has his '${nic}' interface fail ${count} time(s)" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

```
192.168.0.1 has his 'eth1' interface fail 2 time(s)
192.168.0.2 has his 'eth2' interface fail 1 time(s)
192.168.0.2 has his 'eth5' interface fail 1 time(s)
192.168.0.3 has his 'eth3' interface fail 1 time(s)
192.168.0.4 has his 'eth1' interface fail 1 time(s)
```

#### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBS8QwEIXv@RVjCGzClrLtqih19SR4ENx7KRJqSgJrW5LsQUp/e03SFlfYruaU5H3zZt60sh2Gh6dWtgiRD2457IBrzb8oAnfGK07u0zi5vYs3cYIjLKxMMIvOA@kIpIvAdgS2i8CfLa7/OcMNZohlyAXTwhwP1kXLC/euGi14KYGOgbkB4iwYdMEtByIbYyMgtSqhcEVezYKmKqBXyhhh6eSZB7hgc7U/v6Wpqxf6yya573jJagSc4Wb2Q0vQep0hJ59knXbg03oOdo8hoZnb/ZD@N3B@AR4rm2NtT8cSpWwAk84b9SAdK5WBFelcRb8CVVuhK14KqLg6AOmCQQ9WfQpqGIYY9i/79@e31zlHPwzf)

---

<sup>*NIC* --> 'Network Interface Card'</sup>

Comment: Thank you. I just added if ($count > 1) section so it only show the interfaces that failed more than 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$input = array(
    array("192.168.0.1","eth1"),
    array("192.168.0.2","eth2"),
    array("192.168.0.3","eth3"),
    array("192.168.0.1","eth1"),
    array("192.168.0.4","eth1"),
    array("192.168.0.2","eth5"),
);
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($entry) use (&$output) {
    [$host, $interface] = $entry;
    if (isset($host, $output) && isset($interface, $output[$host])) {
        $output[$host][$interface]++;
    } else {
        $output[$host][$interface] = 1;
    }
});
print_r($output);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [192.168.0.1] => Array
        (
            [eth1] => 2
        )
    [192.168.0.2] => Array
        (
            [eth2] => 1
            [eth5] => 1
        )
    [192.168.0.3] => Array
        (
            [eth3] => 1
        )
    [192.168.0.4] => Array
        (
            [eth1] => 1
        )
)
```